# VB.net build solution by ignore error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Greeting everyone, i'm new member and this's my first time to post question on this.

I need your help to advise me how can i ignore the error and build the solution.
From my code has error 'BC30057' about 'Too many arguments' as you see. But i must use many kinds of argument due to this function depend on .dll file (many version with variant agrument) on each computer.

Please advise me, and if you have better solution plese let me know.

=======================================================================

```
   Select Case Group
        Case "A"
            tmpStr = FITSCon.fn_InitDB(FITS_OPN, FITSRev)
        Case "B"
            tmpStr = FITSCon.fn_InitDB(FITS_Model, FITS_OPN, FITSRev, FITSName)
        Case "C"
            tmpStr = FITSCon.fn_InitDB(FITS_Model, FITS_OPN, FITSName)
   End Select
```

=======================================================================

Comment: The error means that you have a call to a method with more arguments that the method has been designed to receive. If you have the source code of this method (fn_InitDB ?) then you can add an overload for it that receives the correct number of arguments. If you don't have the source code then you cannot call that method passing more arguments than those expected

Comment: Are you saying that the method may be declared with a different number of parameters in different versions of a DLL on different machines, or that you only want to pass a subset of the full arguments that changes depending on the circumstances?

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney
As you said, the method declarded with different versions of DLL file example : PC1 use A1.dll and PC2 use A1.2.dll
Both dll has common method name just only different the number arguments call method.

Comment: Hi @Steve ,i don't have the source code of that dll file due to our policy. I'm blind now to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that code is in a file for which `Option Strict` is set to `Off` then you can assign `FITSCon` to a variable of type `Object` and then call your method on that. With `Option Strict Off`, late-binding is permitted so you can use any signature you want in that case, as long as it's valid at run-time.

If you already have `Option Strict Off` for the project (which is the default for VS but I would recommend changing that) then all you need to do is this:

```
Dim FITSConObject As Object = FITSCon

Select Case Group
    Case "A"
        tmpStr = FITSConObject.fn_InitDB(FITS_OPN, FITSRev)
    Case "B"
        tmpStr = FITSConObject.fn_InitDB(FITS_Model, FITS_OPN, FITSRev, FITSName)
    Case "C"
        tmpStr = FITSConObject.fn_InitDB(FITS_Model, FITS_OPN, FITSName)
End Select
```

If you have `Option Strict On` for the project then leave a comment to that effect and I'll provide a detailed explanation of the best course of action, which would involve moving that code to a partial class in a separate code file, so you can turn `Option Strict Off` for the minimum of code.